# How to optimize postgresql query with joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I wrote the query below this cost is around 1770077 I want to reduce the cost please suggest the best option.

```
SELECT  eco.operationalstatus,SI.storecode,count(SI.gustoreid), SI.storename,SI.storetype, PPK.guproductpkgid,PPK.code AS ProductCode, PPK.description as ProductName
    FROM inv_storeinformation as SI
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sms_ecotransaction as et  on SI.gustoreid=et.currentgustoreid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sms_ecomaster as eco  on et.refid=eco.ecoid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sms_productpackagemaster as PPK on eco.guproductid=PPK.guproductpkgid

    Group by eco.operationalstatus,SI.storecode,SI.gustoreid, SI.storename,SI.storetype, PPK.guproductpkgid,PPK.code , PPK.description
    order by SI.storecode,PPK.code
```

When executed, I get the following actual execution plan cost

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=1770077.23..1798321.49 rows=16836 width=661)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1770077.23..1772884.82 rows=1123036 width=661)"
"        Sort Key: si.storecode, ppk.code, eco.operationalstatus, si.gustoreid, si.storename, si.storetype, ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.description"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=62583.69..336765.88 rows=1123036 width=661)"
"              Hash Cond: ((eco.guproductid)::text = (ppk.guproductpkgid)::text)"
"              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=62577.94..321318.39 rows=1123036 width=634)"
"                    Hash Cond: ((et.currentgustoreid)::text = (si.gustoreid)::text)"
"                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=62576.43..305875.13 rows=1123036 width=39)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((et.refid)::text = (eco.ecoid)::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on sms_ecotransaction et  (cost=0.00..24914.25 rows=779925 width=35)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=39803.30..39803.30 rows=1121130 width=40)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on sms_ecomaster eco  (cost=0.00..39803.30 rows=1121130 width=40)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.23..1.23 rows=23 width=612)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on inv_storeinformation si  (cost=0.00..1.23 rows=23 width=612)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4.22..4.22 rows=122 width=44)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on sms_productpackagemaster ppk  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=122 width=44)"
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE" is below

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=1770077.23..1798321.49 rows=16836 width=661) (actual time=154832.599..184209.736 rows=83 loops=1)"
"  Output: eco.operationalstatus, si.storecode, count(si.gustoreid), si.storename, si.storetype, ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.code, ppk.description, si.gustoreid"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1770077.23..1772884.82 rows=1123036 width=661) (actual time=154830.264..183333.793 rows=1096170 loops=1)"
"        Output: eco.operationalstatus, si.storecode, si.storename, si.storetype, ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.code, ppk.description, si.gustoreid"
"        Sort Key: si.storecode, ppk.code, eco.operationalstatus, si.gustoreid, si.storename, si.storetype, ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.description"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 109184kB"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=62583.69..336765.88 rows=1123036 width=661) (actual time=988.629..4165.343 rows=1096170 loops=1)"
"              Output: eco.operationalstatus, si.storecode, si.storename, si.storetype, ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.code, ppk.description, si.gustoreid"
"              Hash Cond: ((eco.guproductid)::text = (ppk.guproductpkgid)::text)"
"              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=62577.94..321318.39 rows=1123036 width=634) (actual time=988.508..3582.942 rows=1096170 loops=1)"
"                    Output: si.storecode, si.storename, si.storetype, si.gustoreid, eco.operationalstatus, eco.guproductid"
"                    Hash Cond: ((et.currentgustoreid)::text = (si.gustoreid)::text)"
"                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=62576.43..305875.13 rows=1123036 width=39) (actual time=988.472..3056.651 rows=1121492 loops=1)"
"                          Output: et.currentgustoreid, eco.operationalstatus, eco.guproductid"
"                          Hash Cond: ((et.refid)::text = (eco.ecoid)::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on public.sms_ecotransaction et  (cost=0.00..24914.25 rows=779925 width=35) (actual time=0.184..316.954 rows=779925 loops=1)"
"                                Output: et.currentgustoreid, et.refid"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=39803.30..39803.30 rows=1121130 width=40) (actual time=981.649..981.649 rows=1121130 loops=1)"
"                                Output: eco.operationalstatus, eco.ecoid, eco.guproductid"
"                                Buckets: 2048  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 645kB"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on public.sms_ecomaster eco  (cost=0.00..39803.30 rows=1121130 width=40) (actual time=0.006..471.218 rows=1121130 loops=1)"
"                                      Output: eco.operationalstatus, eco.ecoid, eco.guproductid"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.23..1.23 rows=23 width=612) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=23 loops=1)"
"                          Output: si.storecode, si.storename, si.storetype, si.gustoreid"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on public.inv_storeinformation si  (cost=0.00..1.23 rows=23 width=612) (actual time=0.009..0.013 rows=23 loops=1)"
"                                Output: si.storecode, si.storename, si.storetype, si.gustoreid"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4.22..4.22 rows=122 width=44) (actual time=0.093..0.093 rows=122 loops=1)"
"                    Output: ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.code, ppk.description"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.sms_productpackagemaster ppk  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=122 width=44) (actual time=0.007..0.038 rows=122 loops=1)"
"                          Output: ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.code, ppk.description"
"Total runtime: 184242.421 ms"
```

Comment: What is the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`? Why do you think the costs are a problem? How long does the query run?

Comment: maybe create some views of some tables, this should be faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have mention the 
EXPLAIN ANALYZE   VERBOSE and running time is 187049 ms

Comment: "*Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 109184kB*" is your main problem. Try to increase the `work_mem` for your session and try again. Which indexes are available on the tables?

Comment: Hash joins will also benfit from `work_mem` increase, along with what @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned.

Comment: The sort takes over 97% of the time: http://explain.depesz.com/s/rU3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  initially `work_mem` is 1MB now i changed to 50 MB even though execution time is    "Total runtime: 232133.584 ms" and am not using any index.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: although that "sort" is caused by the `group by` not by the `order by` (see the columns in the "sort key" part)

Comment: @Pirinthan: Try some 200MB or something like that and run EXPLAIN ANALYZE again to check the query plan. 50MB isn't enough when 109184kB is spilled to disk.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have changed to 250 MB still there are no big changes "Total runtime: 218312.609 ms" but earlier with 50MB  it was "Total runtime: 232133.584 ms"

Comment: ... and how has changing the work_mem affected the explain plan? The sort method, in particular.

Comment: @DavidAldridge "  ->  `Sort  (cost=1770077.23..1772884.82 rows=1123036 width=661) (actual time=186172.369..217351.161 rows=1096170 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: eco.operationalstatus, si.storecode, si.gustoreid, si.storename, si.storetype, ppk.guproductpkgid, ppk.code, ppk.description"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 109176kB"`

Comment: From psql, in the same session that you are executing the query from, what does "show work_mem" give?

Comment: @DavidAldridge after executing this `SET work_mem='250MB'` its took '"Total runtime: 32046.391 ms"' earlier I changed from `postgresql.conf` it didn't change.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your answer is correct. put as a answer i can accept. there was a mistake so work_mem value didn't change. then i run like  `SET work_mem='250MB'` now fine. are there any ways to increase the performance without change the `work_mem`?

Comment: You are grouping 1 million rows over 8 columns. One of them named "description" which indicates potentially long string values. This _is_ going to require memory. There might be better ways to do this if you explain (in a **new** question what the underlying problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: 250MB might be too much of course. You can try reducing it in steps to see how performance changes, and there will likely be particular steps at which performance will deteriorate. You have to consider growth of the data set of course, and you might be able to get a good estimate of the amount of memory required to get optimum performance on this one query based on the number of rows in one of the tables. Then set work_em prior to the query and unset it afterwards.

Comment: I also notice that you're selecting Count(SI.gustoreid) and grouping by the same value. That looks a bit odd, and possibly your meaning would be more clear if you selected "count(*)"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if grouping by SI.gustoreid that is counted in the SELECT section makes sense... If this is yours mistake and you meant count(*) grouped by gustoreid, please consider the query below - subquery reduces number of columns that have to be grouped and it can reduce complexity of the query:

```
SELECT  
    eco.operationalstatus,
    SI.storecode,
    rowCount,
    SI.storename,
    SI.storetype, 
    PPK.guproductpkgid,
    PPK.code AS ProductCode, 
    PPK.description as ProductName
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            storecode,
            count(*) AS rowCount,
            gustoreid, 
            storename,
            storetype   
        FROM
            inv_storeinformation 
        GROUP BY
            storecode,
            storename,
            storetype,
            gustoreid
    ) as SI
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sms_ecotransaction as et  on SI.gustoreid=et.currentgustoreid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sms_ecomaster as eco  on et.refid=eco.ecoid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sms_productpackagemaster as PPK on eco.guproductid=PPK.guproductpkgid
order by 
    SI.storecode,
    PK.code
```